# Xamarin for VS 2015 xaml PCL template fail with: 'There is a missing project subtype'

Tags: visual-studio-2015, xamarin.forms

Since VS 2015 Update2 I am unable to open the Xamarin forms template project in VS (Professional).

I use the following template:

[image: xamarin pcl template]

The following error message occurs when it tries to load the iOS project:

[image]

This issue has only started since VS Update2. I tried repairing and modifying VS as well as updating to the latest Xamarin.

Comment: Sounds like you need to uninstall everything and start again. Uninstall VS, Xamarin etc. and re-install from scratch. Sorry.

Comment: Is there any clue to what caused it so I can avoid it happening again in the future?